# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to send post values in adapter?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I'm using IBM worklight 6.1 for my mobile app project. My question is how to send post values in adapter?

```
function getUsername(userAlias,locale) {
    path = "rest-rib/service/Login/login_username";

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };


    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Is there anything specific that does not work...? Your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question does not specify what is NOT working for you... please add more details.

You should also read about HTTP adapters.

- [Training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf)
- [Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refjavascript-server/html/WL.Server.html#invokeHttp) (scroll down to invokeHttp)
- [Sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/WorklightAdaptersProject.zip)

More:

- [IBM Worklight - Sending HTTP POST request from the client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471483/ibm-worklight-sending-http-post-request-from-the-client-side)
- [how to use plain text in adapter worklight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13449148/how-to-use-plain-text-in-adapter-worklight)

---

Since your question is very dull on details,
The below simple `POST` example is based on this [`POST` method example from W3C Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_method_post).

**Adapter XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<wl:adapter name="PostExample"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>PostExample</displayName>
    <description>PostExample</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>www.w3schools.com</domain>
            <port>80</port> 
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="sendParams"/>
</wl:adapter>
```

**Adapter implementation:**

```
function sendParams() {
    path = "tags/demo_form_method_post.asp";

    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        path: path,
        parameters: {fname: 'idan', lname: 'adar' } 
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```