# Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: http:\/\/staging.xxxxxxx.com"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I can get result from already implemented worklight examples like rss, google map api, etc... But I don't understand how to assess my own API. I am getting the following error:

```
{
   "errors": [
  "Runtime: Http request failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: http:\/\/staging.mycompany.com"
 ],
 "info": [
 ],
 "isSuccessful": false,
 "warnings": [
 ]
  }
```

**myRestAdapter.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <wl:adapter name="myRESTAdapter"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:wl="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration"
xmlns:http="http://www.ibm.com/mfp/integration/http">

<displayName>myRESTAdapter</displayName>
<description>myRESTAdapter</description>
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>http://staging.mycompany.com</domain>
        <port>80</port> 
        <connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>30000</socketTimeoutInMilliseconds>
        <maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>50</maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode>
        <!-- Following properties used by adapter's key manager for choosing specific certificate from key store  
        <sslCertificateAlias></sslCertificateAlias> 
        <sslCertificatePassword></sslCertificatePassword>
        -->     
    </connectionPolicy>
</connectivity>

<procedure name="getGmapLatLng"/>

   </wl:adapter>
```

**myRESTAdapter-impl.js**

```
 function getGmapLatLng(UserName) {

var input = {
    method : 'post',
    returnedContentType : 'application/json',
    path : '/RESTapi/Rest_LoginValidate.php',  // the method which i want to access, actual url is this "http://mycompany.com/RESTapi/LoginValidate.php"
    parameters : {
        'UserName' : UserName,

    }
};

return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the following:

```
<protocol>http</protocol>
<domain>http://staging.mycompany.com</domain>
```

Remove the extra `http://` from the `domain` node.

As for the parameters, see this question: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to send post values in adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014983/ibm-worklight-6-1-how-to-send-post-values-in-adapter)

It should be like this:

```
...
...
function getGmapLatLng(UserName, UserPwd) {
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'application/json',
        path : '/RESTapi/Rest_LoginValidate.php', 
        parameters : {
            UserName : 'UserName', // note the change in place of the quotation marks.
            UserPwd  : 'UserPwd'
        }
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Comment: Hey really thanks for you help @idan, I want to know is it correct which i passed the parameters to post method in "myRESTAdapter-impl.js", Actually i want to pass, Username: pop UserPwd: pop

Comment: Thanks a lot @Idan, I want to post two parameters, i have updated your code, could you tell me is it correct??

Comment: I am getting this error... Backend response content type 'json' did not match the expected content type 'text/html', continue prossesing the response. The request and response headers and body: request:
/RESTapi/Rest_LoginValidate.php

Comment: That's probably because of the returnedContentType that you're using.

Comment: Please do not continue to use this question for more questions. If the original issue of this question is answered - stop there. If you have more questions, open more questions.